# Is checking the value of SESSION variables classed as business logic?

Tags: php, html, optimization

I'm developing my a web application.
I have this piece of code:

```
<?php 
if($_SESSION['add'] == 1) 
echo '<input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="Add" onclick="add()" >';
if($_SESSION['edit'] == 1)
echo '<input type="button" name="edit" id="edit" value="Edit" onclick="edit()">';
?>
```

Basically, when the user logs in, I set session variables which indicate whether or not that user is authorised to make changes and add records. So when they get to the home page, I use this code to decide whether or not to display my add and edit buttons.

Is this code breaking the rule of logic/presentation separation? If so, how can I achieve separation?

I am not using any web framework.

Comment: If add() and edit() are just a javascript function, then people can call them even if they don't have access.

Comment: so how should i fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While conditions in View are perfectly fine, your View should not try to fetch any data from any source by itself. This is not its role and it should only work on data your Controller (or Presenter, depending on whatever your application architecture is) feed it with. Your View shouldn't not know the logic behind  **why** and **when** to switch between `edit` and `add` modes. It only must know **how** to do that when ordered. In your case, Controller should check `$_SESSION` and make the decision what mode, add or edit your View should display and pass that decision to your View (i.e. `action_mode` = `edit|add`) for dumb execution.

PS: I recommend to make a habit to always put code blocks (even one-liners) in `{`, `}` brackets.

Comment: Im having trouble understanding your answers, sorry.

Comment: @Connor In a nutshell: you want to *decouple* your view logic from the specific source of the data, `$_SESSION`. You may in the future have other situations in which something other than the `$_SESSION` decides on the particular edit mode, you don't want to tie that decision directly to the `$_SESSION` variable.